# How to customize a listview in Qt

Tags: qt, listview, qt4, custom-controls, symbian

I want to customize a listview in Qt, can anyone provide me some example or hints of how to do it? I am new to Qt.

Answer (score 4):

You can apply stylesheet to your `QListView`.

Check out [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qlistview) for the Qt documentation of customizing `QListView` using stylesheets.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a standard item model or a QListWidget (or any other model that uses QStandardItem), you can set appearance properties on the items using setData.

So, The following will add a red item to a list widget:

```
QListWidgetItem *colorItem = new QListWidgetItem("Red");
colorItem->setData(QBrush(QColor(Qt::red)), Qt::ForegroundRole);

list.addItem(colorItem);
```

For a working code example and more detailed explanation, please see: http://ynonperek.com/qt-mvc-customize-items